# How to create a matrix with supplied dimensions or create dynamic variable name in Ruby for each subsequent array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, dynamic, matrix

I'd like to create a class and pass 2 variables to that class; width(x) and length(y).  With those variables the program should establish either a matrix or create x number of arrays with y number of entries.

The problem is if it's not a matrix (how?) if arrays are best then how can it work if say 4, 8 were passed?

```
array_name_0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array_name_1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array_name_2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
array_name_3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

where "array_name_x" the x would = the x passed via creation and the 0-7 is based on the y.

Sample code as follows:

```
class Dimensional
  attr_reader :width, :length

  def initialize(width,length)

    @width = width
    @length = length
    @sqft = width * length

  end
  def full
    "
    width : #{@width}
    length: #{@length}
    sq ft : #{@sqft}

    #display array/matrix here

"
  end
end

myDimensional = Dimensional.new(4, 8)

print Dimensional.full
```

so how, in this example, would I create a matrix with those x, y values or how would i dynamically assign "array_name_x" with a number for x based on x provided?

Comment: An array of arrays is the first thing that comes to mind. However, would you have to make any special considerations for a sparse matrix?

Comment: I don't get your meaning... Why didn't Matrix suit your need?

Comment: it's not that matrix didn't suit... i just can't find straight forward examples of how to implement a matrix in this setting (user input to adjust it on creation of object)

Answer (score 0):

`width.times.map{ length.times.to_a }` comes to mind, for example

```
matrix = 3.times.map{ 2.times.to_a }
# => [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

matrix.map{ |row| row.join(" ") }.join("\n")
# 0 1
# 0 1
# 0 1
```